# Android's activity enter transitions won't work as intended on overlapping views

Tags: android, animation, transition

Here is the scenario:

I'm trying to declare transition animation between two activities - master and detail. Master is a `RecyclerView` list with images, detail is `LinearLayout` with header image from parent's list. Transitions are declared in XML and bound to detail activity like so:

```
<item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@transition/activity_enter_shared</item>
<item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/activity_enter</item>
```

In `RecyclerView`'s adapter transition is triggered like so:

```
final ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
    mContext, 
    imgView, 
    ViewCompat.getTransitionName(imgView)
);
mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, ChildActivity.class), options.toBundle());
```

The problem is:
In `@transition/activity_enter` I'm applying `fade` on some layout elements (e.g. back button). Those elements are placed in `FrameLayout` **over an image**. This seems to cause problems with `fade` views, which instead of smoothly appearing on the screen, "pop in". **This only happens** when views are overlapping - if placed in `LinearLayout` everythings works as intended.

`fade` is declared in `@transition/activity_enter` like so:

```
<fade
    android:startDelay="300"
    android:duration="100"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/linear">
    <targets>
        <target android:targetId="@id/target_id" />
    </targets>
</fade>
```

**Note 1** - If triggered programmatically in `Activity` `fade` works fine:

```
final ViewGroup frame = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.frame);
frame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    boolean visible;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(frame);
        visible = !visible;
        frame.findViewById(R.id.target_id).setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
});
```

**Note 2** - Shared transition (`@transition/activity_enter_shared`) is custom, however, using default one doesn't solve the problem.

**Note 3** - In its simplest, layouts looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <ImageView />
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/target_id" />
</FrameLayout/>
```

however, problem is not specific to `FrameLayout` but rather overlapping of views.

**Note 4** - For example, in the following layout *Lorem* will pop in, while  *ipsum* will fade in.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I found an answer, for those interested.

I had to set

```
<item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>
```

in my style definition.

From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#attr_android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay):

> Indicates whether or not shared elements should use an overlay during
>   transitions. The default value is true.